# Angular TypeScript Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: angular, typescript

When running "ng build" for my Angular application i am seeing the following error in the console.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/myModule/myModule.min.js 1:16288-16703
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
    at AMDRequireContextDependency.getWarnings (C:\MyAngularApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\ContextDependency.js:40:18)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (C:\MyAngularApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1416:24)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (C:\MyAngularApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1436:9)
    at C:\MyAngularApp\\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1221:10
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\MyAngularApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\MyAngularApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (C:\MyAngularApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1216:28)
    at C:\MyAngularApp\\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:662:17
    at _done (eval at create (C:\MyAngularApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\MyAngularApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at C:\MyAngularApp\\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1148:12
    at C:\MyAngularApp\\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1060:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:72:11)
 @ ./src/scripts/myScript1.js
 @ ./src/app/component1.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

When running the applications locally (from Visual Studio Code) it runs perfectly OK, however it does not build and run in a proper deployed environment.

**My Application**

My Project Structure

```
| src
   |- app
        |- component1.html
        |- component1.ts   
   | scripts
        | myScript1.js
        | myScript2.js
```

myScript1.js

```
export function s1Func1(s) {....}
```

myScript2.js

```
export function myFunc1(s) {...}
export function myFunc2(s) {...}
export function myFunc3(s) {...}
```

component1.ts

```
import {s1Func1} from '../scripts/myScript1';
import {myFunc1, myFunc2} from '../scripts/myScript2';
```

**Searching for a solution**

I have spent a while searching online for explanations of what this error exactly means and how to resolve it.  There appears to be a number of questions on stack overflow for this but I have tried a number of the suggested solutions and nothing has worked. I also still do not truly understand the cause of the error.

**Fixes I have tried**

*tsconfig.ts*

added "allowJS" in both top level and under "compilerOptions"

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "allowJs": true,  
  "compilerOptions": {
   ....
```

OR

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
       "allowJs": true,  
 ....
```

*angular.json*

added my scripts under "scripts" key

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
     ....
     "projects": {
          .....
          "architect": {
                "build": {
                     ....
                     "options": {
                         ....
                         "scripts": [
                              "src/scripts/myScript1.js,
                              "src/scripts/myScript2.js,
                              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
                         ]
    ....
```

*create ".d.ts" files for each ".js" file*

```
| src
   |- app
        |- component1.html
        |- component1.ts   
   | scripts
        | myScript1.js
        | myScript1.d.ts
        | myScript2.js
        | myScript2.d.ts

myScript1.d.ts
    export function myFunc1(s: String) : String

myScript2.d.ts

    export function myFunc1(s: String) : String
    export function myFunc2(s: String) : String
    export function myFunc3(s: String) : String
```

Comment: Not sure if it will do anything, but try changing **.js** to **.ts**

Comment: Unfortunately I can not do that. The files in the scripts directory are shared among different projects and are not written in typescript/